# Chokidar isn't picking up file changes inside docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker for mac version 1.12.0-rc2 for a react project. My workflow is this:

1. `src/` folder on OS X is mounted to the container
2. When a developer modifies a file in `src/` it gets converted to ES5 and placed in `public/` (this works).
3. When a file is changed in `public/` another watcher triggers hot reloading (works on my localhost but not in the container).

Here's my step watcher code from step 3:

```
// root = "/src"
const watcher = chokidar.watch(root, {
    usePolling: true,
    awaitWriteFinish: {
        pollInterval: 100,
        stabilityThreshold: 250
    },
    ignored: /\.(git|gz|map)|node_modules|jspm_packages|src/,
    ignoreInitial: true,
    persistent: true
})
    .on("change", function fileWatcher(filename) {
        const modulePath = filename.replace(`${root}/`, "");

        wss.clients.forEach(function sendFileChange(client) {
            send("filechange", modulePath, client);
        });

        if (cache[filename]) {
            wss.clients.forEach(function sendCacheFlush(client) {
                send("cacheflush", filename, client);
            });

            delete cache[filename];
        }
    });
```

And my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  wildcat:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        JSPM_GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN:
    image: "nfl/react-wildcat-example:latest"
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
      PORT: 3000
      STATIC_PORT: 4000
      COVERAGE:
      LOG_LEVEL:
      NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED: 0
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: 'true'
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src/src
      - ./api:/src/api
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "4000:4000"
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
    entrypoint: "npm run"
    command: "dev"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After spending a day or two on this I found the issue, the line:

```
ignored: /\.(git|gz|map)|node_modules|jspm_packages|src/,
```

Was causing chokidar to ignore `/src` which was the folder I was copying all the source code to in the docker container. I changed this path in the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml to `/code` instead and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

As a hopefully helpful note to those coming here by the title, Chokidar docs [states](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar):

> It is typically necessary to set this (polling) to true to successfully watch files over a network, and it may be necessary to successfully watch files in other non-standard situations.

On Docker Desktop for Mac 4.0.0, I got Firebase Emulators (that uses Chokidar) to see host-side file changes by:

```
  environments:
  - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

Comment: Thank you, the option `usePolling: true` worked out of the box for me! I hadn't noticed it.